# V particle appearing in FeynArts/FeynCalc

Tags: feyncalc

I have the following problem. I am using Feynarts. I am running the following code:
I am using QEDOnly.

```
topologies2 = 
CreateTopologies[0, 2 -> 2, Adjacencies -> {3}, 
ExcludeTopologies -> {Tadpoles}];
AA3 = InsertFields[
topologies2, {F[2, {1}], F[2, {2}]} -> {F[2, {1}], F[2, {2}]}, 
QEDOnly];
Paint[AA3, ColumnsXRows -> {2, 1}]
```

There are two diagrams, one with a photon, and one with a V particle. Why does this V particle appear? I would like to get rid of it.
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: I suggest reading the manual, or try asking the author of *FeynArts* here: http://www.feynarts.de

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `InsertionLevel` option to `{Classes}`

```
<< FeynArts`
$FAVerbose = 0;

topologies2 = 
  CreateTopologies[0, 2 -> 2, Adjacencies -> {3}, 
   ExcludeTopologies -> {Tadpoles}];
AA3 = InsertFields[
   topologies2, {F[2, {1}], F[2, {2}]} -> {F[2, {1}], F[2, {2}]}, 
   Restrictions -> QEDOnly, InsertionLevel -> {Classes}];
Paint[AA3, ColumnsXRows -> {2, 1}];
```

BTW, QuantumDot is fully right about reading the manual. It is quite short, so you can finish it in less than a day. And this will remove 95% of potential questions you might have regarding the usage of FeynArts.